# What does "racket" mean in this context?

Tags: word-meaning

This is from [a *New York Times* article](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/01/11/opinion/sunday/meghan-markle-harry-royal-family.html) :

> I never had much use for the queen.
>
> Maybe it’s the Irish in me. As Winston Churchill said: “We’ve always
> found the Irish a bit odd. They refuse to be English.”
>
> Or maybe it’s the American in me. We did go to an awful lot of trouble
> to break away from that corgi-and-gin-loving **racket** 244 years ago.

I understand that the term "**racket**" is used metaphorically presumably referring to the British monarchy but I'm curious what the literal meaning of 'racket' is here.

Does it mean '[a loud unpleasant noise](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/racket?q=racket)'?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case "racket" is more likely being used to mean [a nefarious scheme or scam](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/racket) as seen in the 3rd and 4th definitions.

The "racket" is likely referring to the monarchy as being a suspicious or dubious scheme to defraud or deceive people.

It's often used to describe explicit criminal activity, such as racketeering, but can also be used to refer to any situation where one group of people takes advantage of others to make a profit by deceptive means.

For example if you discover that a store is charging a huge markup on an item that's hard to get, you might describe them as running a racket.

In this specific case, the tone of the article seems to be humorous, so it's not likely that the author is actually claiming the monarchy is a fraudulent enterprise. Instead it's probably being used tongue-in-cheek.

The mention of a "lot of trouble" is referencing US independence in 1776. However the US and Britain are now close allies, so that and the "corgi-and-gin-loving racket" comment both suggest a friendly bantering form of humor rather than an actual insult.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: A 'racket' can be used humorously-deprecatingly about any habitual activity at all, and is common in British English. I was in the teaching racket for 15 years and left to become an accountant.

Comment: Of course, King George III didn't keep corgis and probably didn't drink gin!

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thank you very much.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you very much.

Comment: It may be worth noting that the New York Times article is very clearly humorous.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Noted, and I've added that to my answer